# Grid View not getting refreshed with drop down.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="RequestType1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Stock_Market">Stock Market</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Night_Shift">Night Shift</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Air_Port">Air Port</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="810px" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">

  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConString %>" SelectCommand="select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and group_no IS NULL"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I got a gridview and a dropdown list and a sqldatasource , when the page is loading the gridview will load the default query from the sqldata source. When each option is selected with the dropdownlist , the appropriate queries will be loaded as follows.

```
 if (RequestType1.Text == "All")
        {

            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and group_no IS NULL";

        }
        else if (RequestType1.Text == "Stock_Market")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and req.service_type='Stock_Market ' and group_no IS NULL";

        }
        else if (RequestType1.Text == "Night_Shift")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and req.service_type='Night_Shift' and group_no IS NULL";

        }
        else if (RequestType1.Text == "Air_Port")
        {

            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and req.service_type='Air_Port' and group_no IS NULL";
        }
        else if (RequestType1.Text == "Other")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and req.service_type='Other' and group_no IS NULL";

        }
```

But the gridview isn't getting refreshed for the option 'All'. It has this query

```
 SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and group_no IS NULL";
```

But it does get refreshed , when i added some other query. The relationship is that the default query of the sqldata source and the query for option 'All' is same. So, any solutions how to load the values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
       if (RequestType1.Text == "All")
        {

            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and group_no IS NULL";

        }
        else if (RequestType1.Text == "Stock_Market")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and req.service_type='Stock_Market ' and group_no IS NULL";

        }
        else if (RequestType1.Text == "Night_Shift")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and req.service_type='Night_Shift' and group_no IS NULL";

        }
        else if (RequestType1.Text == "Air_Port")
        {

            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and req.service_type='Air_Port' and group_no IS NULL";
        }
        else if (RequestType1.Text == "Other")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select req.request_no ,emp.employee_name,req.requested_date, req.requested_time, req.requested_from, req.requested_to,req.reason_data from Request_List req, Employee emp where req.added_by=emp.employee_id and req.service_type='Other' and group_no IS NULL";

        }
        GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```